# Nested Dictionaries or DataTable

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable, nested

What would be the smartest way to have a 3 "column" dictionary. I need an ID, Name, and Commision. Would it be best to just throw it in a DataTable? or would that be too bulky? I have the name, and I only want to have to go to the DB once to get the ID and Commission. That said, I will be doing a lot of checks for the existence of the Name value. Obviously, if it doesn't exist, I'll need to grab the ID and Commission for the DB, and add the record to the collection. So DataTable? Nested Dictionary? Other? What do you guys think?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would the dictionary need to be nested?  You just need one dictionary.  Why would you use a `DataTable` to look up values based on a key?  That's not at all what `DataTable` is designed for, and it's *exactly* what `Dictionary` is designed for.

Comment: If you only ever need to look it up by the name, a dictionary with that as a key seems like a good fit.

Comment: Dictionary with Name as key and define a class or struct to hold the Id/Commission? You could also store a Tuple if you really are adverse to making a new class or struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Element
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Commission {get; set;}
}

var data = new Dictionary<string,Element>();
data.Add(e.ID,e); //assuming e is of type Element and defined.
```

Comment: I guess I wouldn't really need the Name field, since it's the key, but I get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the database most generally the Name field isn't constrained to be unique.  The Dictionary requires all keys to be unique so ID would probably be the best choice.

Comment: Oh okay, I get that. I'm reading from an excel file where only the name is provided, so I figured I'd need to use that as the key. I've been assuming that the name is unique. But you're right, I need to make sure that's a safe assumption, or there will be more issues :-p thanks!